# Calculate column of JTable and display in JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I try to create point of sale program that connected to MySQL database. I have one `JTable` to display the item serial and item name and price I want to get sum of total price in `jTextField8` as total I write the following:

```
try {
        String sql = "Select * from ITEMB where ITEM =13";
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String myNamatxt = rs.getString("PRISE");
            String myHargatxt = rs.getString("ITEMNAME");
            String satuan = rs.getString("ITEM");
            String[] data = {myNamatxt, myHargatxt, satuan,};
            tabMode.addRow(data);
            double price = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("prise"));
            totalpay = price + totalpay;
            ++rowcount;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ignore
    }
    jTextField8.setText(String.valueOf(totalpay));
}
```

When I try to start new bill, the text field doesn't return to zero and start by total of previous bill.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { //ignore }`  No.. don't ignore it!  At the very least: `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: thank pro i will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset `totalPay` to `0` before when you need to re-load values or create a new bill